# Design an N-Integer synthesizer with PLL (calculate R C of the LPF and constants of the PLL blocks)

Tags: transfer-function, pll, vco

I need to design an N-Integer synthesizer with PLL to generate the carrier signal for a WLAN transmission according to the 802.11b standard (2.412 GHz to 2.484 GHz with 20 MHz of bandwidth for each carrier.) I have a VCO with a 2.3 GHz - 2.5 Ghz band I can use. Below the schema.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKHups.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Where `K_PD` and `K_VCO` are the constants of the phase detector and the VCO. N divider is the divider for the referance frequency that, in my case ,is 1 MHz (N divider varies between 2412 and 2484 according to which frequency I'm tracking.)

To design the PLL I have a VCO with a bandwith from 2.3 GHz to 2.5 GHz and  = 1. The LPF must have a bandwidth of 50 kHz.

With this information I need to find R1, C1 of the LPF and `K_PD` and `K_VCO` of the PLL but I have no idea where to start.

I know the transfer function of the PLL in my scheme is:

$$
T_N(s) = \frac{1}{1+sR_1C_1}\frac{K_{PD}K_{VCO}}{s}\frac{1}{N}
$$

I know the equation  and _n but still I can't understand how to proceed.

I have calculated R1 and C1 given the bandwidth of my filter but there are multiple solutions because of the position of where I want to put my pole in the transfer function.

Comment: Is this a class assignment with an attempt from your instructor to provide some 'real-world' context? If that's the case, then Marcus' otherwise good answer probably doesn't really help, since your instructor would probably prefer some sort of PLL design from you rather than a 'your approach is doomed' answer...

Comment: Absolutely right! If that's the case, let us know – we'll have to figure out which parts of IEEE802.11b your instructor meant and which not.

Comment: @brhans yes, it's an assignment. I have added more info on the comments below Marcus answer

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've added more info, including the raw text for the assignment, in the below comments

Comment: I would have thought the filter needs to have an extra R in series with C1, called a "passive lag" filter (but more like a pole-zero).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen on my assignment it is asked for an RC filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Remark: This answer was written under a false assumption; doesn't answer the question.

**Still leaving it here, until somebody writes a better one.**

> WLAN 802.11b (2.412 GHz to 2.484 GHz with 20 MHz of bandwidth for each carrier

That's incorrect. 802.11b had 5 or 12 MHz bandwidth. So, probably you're referring to 802.11a/g/n:

Your approach is doomed; the carrier is typically suppressed in a Wifi transmission; here's a 802.11n (or ac) transmission (which uses OFDM, unlike 802.11b, which is DSSS).

[image: Waterfall diagram of a typical Wifi transmission, 80 MHz]
From Cisco23500 on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNHSAZwTcio)

As you can see: this waveform is very flat, and has a nearly rectangular band edge which means that not even a wider LPF for your PLL will save you. There's really not a phase you can lock on.

---

Even if it's *actually* about 802.11b:
I'd try to capture 802.11b for you, but it seems I have no device left that uses it! So, will have to refer to [keysight](http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/ads2008/adswtbwlan/ads2008/WLAN_802_11b_TX.html):

[image: Keysight observed spectrum vs mask]

As you can see, there's actually even a small notch at the carrier frequency. Again, everything is wide, no carrier to lock on, at least a band-edge FLL would work, but that would usually be too noisy to suffice for communications purposes.

---

So, in both cases, **a PLL is useless** here. You'll need to use one of the data-aided methods that these standards foresee. For OFDM-based Wifi, you'll really want to read about Schmidl-Cox synchronizations, and I'd assume (it's been quite a while) that 802.11b simply uses a known sequence to correlate accordingly; after all, it uses a Barker code for spreading, so a simple correlator bank should give a fairly good frequency estimate.

Comment: Good answer, but I wonder if this is really a class assignment from a misguided instructor who tried (but failed) to provide some 'real-world' context...

Comment: If that's the case, I'll probably update the answer soon as we know what about the assignment / 802.11b we can ignore, and what we can't. In fact, it's relatively complicated to do this right – the question specifically mentions high bandwidths, but doesn't mention any carrier recovery methods (e.g. squaring), which you could use to get rid of the data phase, which thanks to the modulation with source coded data should be pretty much cancel out, anyway. But implementing something like that comes with its own can of worms. Soooooo... let's hope this helps, and if not, let's hope for comments!

Comment: @brhans I've just reported the text of the assignment. That's literally the text "Transmission on 14 channels of 20 MHz band with carriers between 2.412 GHz and 2.484 GHz." and also "Suppose you want to design an N-Integer synthesizer with PLL to generate the carrier signal for a WLAN transmission according to the 802.11b standard. You have a VCO with a 2.3 GHz band at your disposal 2.5 GHz for an input voltage of 0V to 10V."

Comment: EDIT You have a VCO with a 2.3 GHz - 2.5 GHz band at your disposal

Comment: I got that the bandwidth is 5MHz but why on the right graph it shows 22MHz? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11b-1999

Comment: @NicoCaldo thanks for the info! Your question is a bit different than your assignment: The assignment says *synthesize a tone for ... *, whereas your question is *how to track the carrier of ...*, I think you might understand how these are two different things! I'd strongly recommend **editing** your question to include the original assignment wording!

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks a lot for your clarification. I'm not very knowledgeable about these devices as it's the first time I'm seeing and studying them